# element wise combine list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do some linear combination of numpy arrays.

I have three lists of numpy arrays:

`a = [np.random.normal(0,1, [1,2]), np.random.normal(0,1, [3,4]), np.random.normal(0,1, [10,11])]
b = [np.random.normal(0,1, [1,2]), np.random.normal(0,1, [3,4]), np.random.normal(0,1, [10,11])] 
c = [np.random.normal(0,1, [1,2]), np.random.normal(0,1, [3,4]), np.random.normal(0,1, [10,11])]`

I want to element-wise combine each element in each array in list `a` and `b` based on corresponding element's value of `c` , to get a new list `d`: say `d_i = a_i * c_i + (1-c_i) *b_i`(linear combination).

What I thought was to pick each element in each array in `a` and find corresponding elements in `b` and `c` and then combine. However, I found this is troublesome, inefficient and a bit stupid. Could anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Added `d_i = a_i * c_i + (1-c_i) *b_i`, where each variable denotes each element in each array in list.

Comment: Why do you have lists of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming all of your lists are the same length then I don't think that there is going to be anything much more efficient than

```
d = [a[i] * c[i] + (1-c[i]) * b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Now if all you need to do is operate upon the list `d` one time then maybe you could speed things up with a generator comprehension?

```
d = (a[i] * c[i] + (1-c[i]) * b[i] for i in range(len(a)))
```

But at the end of the day there is no way to create a linear combination of elements in less than linear time.

Comment: Ideally a list comprehension is the most efficient for creating a list. However, as you say if you have further operations, it's good to defer list creation.

Comment: Wow, you are clever!

Comment: @xaav I can update to use a list comprehension, but a generator comprehension is truly the most efficient as it doesn't save anything unnecessarily if the list is only being traversed once.

Comment: You reminds me `d = [], for x, y, z in zip(a,b, c): d.append(z*x + (1-z) *y)`, could anyone comments on this way?

Comment: It depends what y'all mean by "efficient". List comprehensions are marginally faster than equivalent for-loops at constructing lists. If you don't actually need a list, and merely need to process each element, then a generator-expression or some form of lazy-iterable would be ideal.

Comment: @ytutow That is horrible.

Comment: Yeah @ytutow you are `zip`ing the things together unnecessarily. So you are constructing a tuple and then unpacking it for no reason other than readability.